# Not able to click on menu option from selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, ui-automation, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select menu option for my WebApp, Able to click on the menu, menu options are also visible But not able to click on menu option.

From Selenium API if I try to check the visibility of the menu option, It says not visible but infact it's already visible on the screen.

Is there any standard of selecting the menu and menu option using Selenium IE Driver.

Following is the menu/menu-options code:

```
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 2px outset; POSITION: absolute; BORDER-LEFT: 2px outset; WIDTH: 162px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND: #e4e4e4; HEIGHT: 106px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; BORDER-TOP: 2px outset; TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 2px outset; LEFT: 0px">
<DIV style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; HEIGHT: 17px; COLOR: black; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 2px" onmouseover="this.style.background='darkblue';this.style.color='white';" onmouseout="this.style.background=this.runtimeStyle.background;this.style.color='black';" onclick="parent.smConfig_Click(0,'smConfig0')"><SPAN>Config. Management</SPAN> </DIV><INPUT id=lgx_smConfig01 type=hidden SP="" LP="<LinkParams lgx_ID='WideDetail'  FromDate='@Data.DefaultDate.FromDate~' ToDate='@Data.DefaultDate.ToDate~' lgx_DetailID='dtlConfig' FirstTime='1' ConfigType='2'  />" Modal="" Features="" Target="_top" Action="lgx_Frame.aspx"> 
<DIV style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; HEIGHT: 17px; COLOR: black; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 2px" onmouseover="this.style.background='darkblue';this.style.color='white';" onmouseout="this.style.background=this.runtimeStyle.background;this.style.color='black';" onclick="parent.smConfig_Click(1,'smConfig1')"><SPAN>Custom Configuration</SPAN> </DIV><INPUT id=lgx_smConfig11 type=hidden SP="" LP="<LinkParams lgx_ID='Default'  lgx_ListID='lstCustomConfig' ConfigType='1'  />" Modal="" Features="" Target="_top" Action="lgx_Frame.aspx"> 
<DIV style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; HEIGHT: 17px; COLOR: black; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 2px" onmouseover="this.style.background='darkblue';this.style.color='white';" onmouseout="this.style.background=this.runtimeStyle.background;this.style.color='black';" onclick="parent.smConfig_Click(2,'smConfig2')"><SPAN>Custom Transition</SPAN> </DIV><INPUT id=lgx_smConfig21 type=hidden SP="" LP="<LinkParams lgx_ID='Default'  lgx_ListID='lstCustomTransition' Flag='512' Title='Custom'  />" Modal="" Features="" Target="_top" Action="lgx_Frame.aspx"> 
<DIV style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; HEIGHT: 17px; COLOR: black; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 2px" onmouseover="this.style.background='darkblue';this.style.color='white';" onmouseout="this.style.background=this.runtimeStyle.background;this.style.color='black';" onclick="parent.smConfig_Click(3,'smConfig3')"><SPAN>Person Hierarchy Level</SPAN> </DIV><INPUT id=lgx_smConfig31 type=hidden SP="" LP="<LinkParams lgx_ID='Default'  lgx_ListID='lstPersonLevel'  />" Modal="" Features="" Target="_top" Action="lgx_Frame.aspx"> 
<DIV style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; HEIGHT: 17px; COLOR: black; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 2px" onmouseover="this.style.background='darkblue';this.style.color='white';" onmouseout="this.style.background=this.runtimeStyle.background;this.style.color='black';" onclick="parent.smConfig_Click(4,'smConfig4')"><SPAN>Role</SPAN> </DIV><INPUT id=lgx_smConfig41 type=hidden SP="" LP="<LinkParams lgx_ID='Default'  lgx_ListID='lstRoleConfig'  />" Modal="" Features="" Target="_top" Action="lgx_Frame.aspx"> 
<DIV style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; HEIGHT: 17px; COLOR: black; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 2px" onmouseover="this.style.background='darkblue';this.style.color='white';" onmouseout="this.style.background=this.runtimeStyle.background;this.style.color='black';" onclick="parent.smConfig_Click(5,'smConfig5')"><SPAN>Status</SPAN> </DIV><INPUT id=lgx_smConfig51 type=hidden SP="" LP="<LinkParams lgx_ID='Default'  lgx_ListID='lstStatusTy'  />" Modal="" Features="" Target="_top" Action="lgx_Frame.aspx"> </DIV></DIV>
```

In the above menu options code, I need to click on **Role** option.
This options are visible on click on **configure** menu, But click on any of such menu options are not happening, Its also not throwing any exception too.

Please let me know your comments or suggestion to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Tried code 1:

```
WebElement configMenu = driver.findElement(By.id("mConfigLabel"));
configMenu.click();
WebElement menuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='oMenuCntxtsmConfig']/div/div[4]"));
menuOption.click();
```

Tried code 2:

```
WebElement configMenu = driver.findElement(By.id("mConfigLabel"));
configMenu.click();
WebElement menuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/descendant:span[contains(text(),'Role']"));
menuOption.click();
```

Tried code 3:

```
configMenu.click();
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement roleMenuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='oMenuCntxtsmConfig']/div/div[4]"));
builder.moveToElement(configMenu).click(roleMenuOption).build().perform();
```

Tried code 4:

```
WebElement configMenu = driver.findElement(By.id("mConfigLabel"));
configMenu.click();
WebElement roleMenuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='oMenuCntxtsmConfig']/div/div[4]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", roleMenuOption);
```

Comment: What code your are trying?Could you paste it here?

Comment: @Abhi_Mishra Thanks Abhi for reply, I've put four sample codes which I've tried but didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question you are just clicking on the division.

**Your html code says that an onclick event is associated with div.**
This onClick event may be making your input(Which is given as hidden initially) visible.

Now **you need to click on this input too**.

For example for clicking on Role option you need to append this line

```
driver.findElementByID("lgx_smConfig41").click();
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me try, I'll give you update soon.

Comment: I tried with that but It throws ElementNotVisibleException, So I tried  using JavascriptExecutor : 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); 
But no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

playing with Dropdown/menu using selenium is tricky since the dropdown/Menu items are hidden and are not visible until user clicks on Dropdown/Menu.

Your approach is bit right and bit wrong..

***Right*** the way you are accessing the Dropdown/Menu

***Wrong*** the way you are accessing the Items inside the Dropdown/Menu, since they are not directly accessible being hidden in Menu/Dropdown list.

please see the below code for correctly accessing a particular Menu item,

```
WebElement DropdownList = driver.findElement(By.id("mConfigLabel"));
Select clickThis = new Select(DropdownList);
clickThis.selectByValue("Role");
```

I'm assuming the ID of your men/Dropdown to be "mConfigLabel"

There are different code flavors on stackover flow for accessing a menu Item...please do have a look.

Hope this helps....All the best :)